# How can I make a array of windows in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a array of all my `Windows` and it looks something like that:

```
public static void ClassesStart()
{
    Window[] windowList = new Window[3];   
    windowList[0] = mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    windowList[1] = location = new Location();
    windowList[2] = Choices = new Choices();
}
```

it always does errors for the windows names (even whene I do this: `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();`, and then putting it in the array).

please help here :P

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You havent declared these variables mainWindow, location, Choices. But you can do it like this

```
Window[] windowList = new Window[3] {new MainWindow(),new Location(),new Choices()};
var mainWindow = windowList[0] ;
var location = windowList[1] ;
var Choices = windowList[2] ;
```